# Selenium click saved element after reload

Tags: python, selenium

How can I do something like this assuming every time each of these "buttons" pressed the page is reloading

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='name']")
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option in all_options:
    print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("value"))
    option.click()
```

*This code is copied from the examples: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html*

Without getting an Error like this?

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:8329:1)
    at Utils.getElementAt (file:///tmp/tmpIxNh0L/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:7922:10)
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmpIxNh0L/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8957:11)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmpIxNh0L/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11618:15)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpIxNh0L/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11635:11)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpIxNh0L/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11640:7)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpIxNh0L/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11582:5)
```

Answer (score 2):

`StaleElementReferenceException` generally means the page has changed.  The `all_options` list you built is no longer valid, as the page probably changed with the first click on the option.

I'd do something like build a list of values, then use `Select` functionality and iterate through that list of values:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='name']")
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
optionValue = []
for option in all_options:
    print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("value"))
    optionValue.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

selectBox = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='name']"))
for value in optionValue:
    selectBox.select_by_value(value)
```

Comment: Does `select_by_value` have anything to do with the attribute "value"?
I mean, what if my unique attribute is "href"?

Comment: @elichai2 `select_by_value` will click the option in a `select` that matches the value.  Similarly, `select_by_text` will click the option in a `select` that matches the text.

Comment: the `Select` can be the whole `driver`. right? And I meant if my WebElement look like this: `<a class="_54nc" href="/ajax/groups/admins_get.php?gid=401629756682230&uid=100001174794883&source=profilebrowser&action=add_admin" rel="dialog-post" role="menuitem">
<span class="_54nh">Make Admin</span>
</a>`
So my 'Unique' attribute is href.

Comment: @elichai2 As a note, you can edit your post and add to it later.  The example in your question looks like a standard `<select>` + `<option>` setup, but what you're posting here looks quite different.  If you could edit your post, and add the HTML you are trying to interact with, I can update my answer to better help you.

Comment: ok. I'll rewrite the whole. post. I thought I could give an example and that's it but I guess it won't work.

Comment: OK. I just iterated over all the elements again each time the page reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to go about this a different way, each time the page loads your list of elements is dirty and no longer exists.  Therefore it seems you should loop through all elements getting their value and storing it in a list.   Then you should iterate that list to possibly find elements based on their xpath value that have a value of what you have in your list.  Than click that element.  This way you don't have a list of expired elements, but instead you're working from a list of values that you can use to build valid xpath expressions to do the same thing.